# Ques from exam: sequence of functions and improper integrals

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, improper-integrals

$P_n(x):R\rightarrow R$ is a sequence of functions defined by: $$P_n(x)= \frac{n}{1+n^2x^2}$$

f:R->C is continuous and 2pi periodic. We define:

$$f_n(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x-t)P_n(t)dt$$

I should prove that $f_n \rightarrow f$ **uniformly** in $\mathbb R$.

This is an excercise from final test in calculus. My guess is that it is somehow related to Fourier. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Idea: $\frac1\pi\frac{n}{1+n^2x^2}$ is an [approximation to the identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nascent_delta_function#Approximations_to_the_identity).